# How to manage chunking and output filename?

Tags: node.js, webpack, build

I am using the latest version of webpack in Node.js. It's working well but I don't want chunked files, and I also want to handle filenames dynamically if I enter SCSS and js both then filename generate CSS file with js extensions.

I want to compile only SCSS and other rest folder copy to public folder, like images, fonts, libs...

```js
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const WebpackRTLPlugin = require('webpack-rtl-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/assets/scss/app.scss',
    bootstrap: './src/assets/scss/bootstrap.scss',
    icons: './src/assets/scss/icons.scss',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/assets'),
    // filename: 'js/[name].min.js', // // i want to handle this
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.scss'],
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              outputPath: 'images', // folder name
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              outputPath: 'fonts', // folder name
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name].min.css',
    }),
    // new WebpackRTLPlugin(),

    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: 'src/assets/images', // Source image folder
          to: 'images', // Output directory for images
        },
        {
          from: 'src/assets/js', // Source js folder
          to: 'js', // Output directory for js
        },
        // {
        //     from: 'src/assets/libs', // Source libs folder
        //     to: 'libs', // Output directory for libs
        // },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

I tried adding chunk optimizations, but it didn't work.

```
optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              name: 'vendors',
              chunks: 'all',
            },
          },
        },
      },
```